# Define $ f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Define $ f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$ by 
$$f(z)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if } Re(z)=0\text{ or }Im(z)=0\\z & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Then the set of points where $f$ is analytic is:

> (a) $\{z:Re(z)\neq 0$ and $Im(z)\neq 0\}$,
>   (b) $\{z:Re(z)\neq 0$ or $Im(z)\neq 0\}$,
>   (c) $\{z:Re(z)\neq 0\}$,
>   (d) $\{z:Im(z)\neq 0\}$.

my think all the options are correct. because if consider option a) then the function $f$ will be $f(z)=z$ and it is a polynomial function. hence analytic. but for option b) if let $Re(z)\neq 0\}$ but $\{z:Im(z)= 0\}$ then the function $f$ will be $f(z)=0$ and it is also analytic. similarly we can say every option is correct. Am I right? please help me.

Comment: You are aware that "the set of points where $f$ is analytic" allows only *one* answer?

Comment: what does it mean? i am not getting ur answer Sir. please elaborate.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256278/f-mathbb-c-rightarrow-mathbb-c-defined-by-fz-0-if-rez-0-or-imz?rq=1

Comment: I am seeing that for option b) for some values $f(z)=0$ and for another vales $f(z)=z$. Is it necessary to hold analytic always $f$ has to be same function for all given values z.